# Non-closed contours in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, polyline, qgis

While implementing (the wonderful matplotlib) contouring in a GIS preprocessor, the results are slightly undesired [see attached image for references].

Instead of ideally exhibiting polyline segments (circled orange region), the results are closed polygon loops (green highlighted path).

[image: contour example]

My best inference of the logic at play; from left to right in the attached image, the contour levels are decreasing.  The loops being closed suggests that matplotlib.pyplot.contours() is incorporating all values within the bounds of said levels - hence the closed loop?

The goal is having these roughly perpendicular contour levels to clip off at the bounds of said shape.  Considering the paths for these contours are grabbed and plotted in an alternate means to pyplot - the built in masking and clipping seem like they might not be applicable.

Perhaps there is an argument from the docs I am overlooking in the initial contour creation - or some other means to fulfill the needs described?

Thanks for clues or wisdom.

Current Input(s):

*(the meshXList,meshYList,and valueZList are isotropic grid centroid coordinates located within the shown polygon)*

```
X = np.array(self.meshXList).reshape(self.numRows,self.numCols)
Y = np.array(self.meshYList).reshape(self.numRows,self.numCols)
Z = np.array(self.valueZList).reshape(self.numRows,self.numCols)

conIntrv = float(self.conIntNum.text())
minCon,maxCon = float(self.minConLineNum.text()),float(self.maxConLineNum.text())
numCon = int((maxCon-minCon)/conIntrv)
levels = np.linspace(minCon,maxCon,numCon)

contours = plt.contour(X,Y,Z,levels,antialiased=True)
conCollect = contours.collections

rawContourLines = []
for lineIdx, line in enumerate(conCollect):
    lineStrings = []
    for path in line.get_paths():
        if len(path.vertices)>1:
            lineStrings.append(path.vertices)
    rawContourLines.append(lineStrings)
```

## ***Update with related resolve:***

Highest regard @tom10 for cluing in what should have been obvious to me.
The gray area in the attached image was included in the meshXList, meshYList, and valueZList; although not displayed by choice in the GIS program.

Understanding that the valueZList does not require numerical values (was using -999.99999999999), but rather can incorporate {None} revealed an extremely simple solution to the problem:

```
    emptValue = None
    self.valueZList = [emptValue]*len(self.meshXList)
    with open(valueFile, "r") as valueInput:
        reader = csv.reader(valueInput)
        for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
            if idx==0: self.valueType = row[1]
            if idx>0:
                holdingIdx = int(row[0])
                holdingVal = float(row[1])
                if '888.88' in holdingVal or '777.77' in holdingVal:
                    self.valueZList[holdingIdx] = emptValue
                else:
                    self.valueZList[holdingIdx]=holdingVal
                    if holdingVal<minValue: minValue = holdingVal
                    if holdingVal>maxValue: maxValue = holdingVal
```

Horray for the 'None Type'.
[image: proper bounding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the region outside your boundary to `None`.  So to modify a [standard example](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) to give "open" contours:

[image]

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

Z[X<-1] = None
Z[X>2] = None

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=np.arange(-.5, 2, .5))
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.show()
```

Or, a little more fun (using, `Z[X*X+(Y-1)**2>3.] = None`):

[image]

Comment: Wow.  This looks interesting and also tricky for the application in question.  The seemingly infinite variety of polygonal shapes which represent the cut-off for each contour would have to be assessed.  Such that each contours proximity threshold with respect to a buffer of the polygon perimeter would spawn the x and y coordinates of said intersect, and provide the None range to each contour?  Of course, I might be misunderstanding the use of None in this case.

Comment: Your last example for the equation of a circle as the None-clip seems to be the route.  While I am able to easily access a polygon geometry, or perimeter for that matter; implementing such as a set of equations for None-clip is a bit outside my mathematical bounds at current.  Would an irregular polygon form be possible in such an application?

Comment: @Katalpa: In your figure, you've made some area pixels gray (I assume to show that these aren't included in your analysis) and other pixels are non-gray.  All I'm saying is calculate your contours on an array where the gray pixels have the value `None`.

Comment: **It is that simple**.  Hurray for the None type.  Thanks!